# How to record gameplay on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, game-recording

I need to record my wp7 game gameplay like on Hot Apps from channel 9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Hot-Apps/Hot-Apps-Minesweeper-Cheezia-Interior-Design-Talking-Alien-Zombie-Squish.

My current game is written on Silverlight, but I will have XNA games latter as well, so I need some solution which will work for both technologies. If there any free software? If yes is there any way to record video from real device, not emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) will allow you to record video from your computer for free. This is probably the best solution, since I don't know of any way to record video from a Windows Phone on the phone itself. Though you could point a camera at the phone and record things that way.

Comment: Expression encoder can do what I need. I was thinking it will record mouse as well but I was wrong. Mouse recording can be desabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered looking into integrating replays into your game instead?

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064317/conceptually-how-does-replay-work-in-a-game) a while back on StackOverflow a while back which garnered some good replies.

*Edit*

Replays have many more secondary benefits that span from debugging and testing, to demoing, to supporting casting for esports (for a phone game, not a big deal, I know).

Answer (score 0):

[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) works really well for capturing the high frame rate in games